# Duplicate AWS S3 Bean on Spring, but duplicate is nowhere to be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3

We just created a custom `AmazonS3Client` with credentials on a project that was already using Amazon S3 functionality:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Configuration
public class S3Config {

    @Bean
    public static AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client(final AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
        return (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }
}
```

It has worked just fine on all other project, but for some reason, when starting up the application, we get this error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in foo.bar.MyService required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - amazonS3Client: defined by method 'amazonS3Client' in class path resource [foo/bar/S3Config.class]
    - amazonS3: defined in null
```

Nowhere, absolutely nowhere on the project we have an `amazonS3` Bean defined.

So, what are the contents of this Service class? Well, nothing special:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.net.URL;

@Service
public class MyService {
    private final AmazonS3Client s3Client;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(AmazonS3Client s3Client) {
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
    }

    ...
}
```

It is supposed to use the `AmazonS3Client` we just created, and according to the first match of the error message it matched it just fine. If I delete my `S3Config` class, the bean duplication error is gone.

We don't want to force the project to use our `AmazonS3Client` implementation by adding the `@Primary` annotation.

So, what could we be doing wrong?

Comment: IntelliJ is your friend, it can read Spring Config and show beans!

Comment: Do you have any Spring Cloud or similar support that might be auto-configuring one? Normally it should be able to select the beans by type if you don't require a specific name.

Comment: @Snickers3192 Yeah, that's true. I did some research at the time, and found the list of all the beans under Spring/Beans. There were *a lot*, but sadly couldn't find it helpful as it lacks a search functionality (and couldn't find the `amazonS3` Bean, just the one that I just created).

Comment: @chrylis none that I'm aware of =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of debugging, we realized the Service's constructor's parameter name was not exactly named as the Bean. We renamed it so that it matched the Bean's name:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final AmazonS3Client s3Client; //Just fine

    @Autowired
    public MyService(AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client) { // Must match the bean name
        this.s3Client = amazonS3Client;
    }

    ...
}
```

And the Bean duplication error was gone. All we have to do is **name the constructor's parameter just like the bean**.